# Exception: ActionDispatch::Http::MimeNegotiation::InvalidType

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sentry

I have error report in Sentry. How can I fix it?

**ActionDispatch::Http::MimeNegotiation::InvalidType**

{#context['com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.httpservletresponse'].addheader('o0scxl85'" is not a valid MIME type

*Most recent lines of logs are:*

actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_negotiation.rb in rescue in block in content_mime_type at line 31

actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_negotiation.rb in block in content_mime_type at line 24

rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/request.rb in fetch at line 69
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/request.rb in fetch_header at line 69

Answer (score 4):

[It will be helpful if you post the version of rails & sentry.]

As per my knowledge, latest versions of sentry-ruby already ignore this exception. Please check the [commit](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-ruby/commit/8cb0fedd74c8393f1e94e85b487c76ebcb3b8ab5). So, upgrading the sentry-ruby should solve your problem.
If you wan't to handle it yourself, you need to add a custom middleware that catches the exception and send the response.

Reference: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/35604#issuecomment-835274505